# Regex For Finding Ctypes with Int32

Tags: regex, vb.net, recursion

(Hey all,

I am looking for a little regex help...

I am trying to find all CType(expression,Int32) s and replace them with CInt(expression)

This, however, is proving quite difficult, considering there could be a nested Ctype(expression, Int32) within the regex match.  Does anyone have any ideas for how to best go about doing this?

Here is what I have now:

```
Dim str As String = "CType((original.Width * CType((targetSize / CType(original.Height, Single)), Single)), Int32)"
Dim exp As New Regex("CType\((.+), Int32\)")
str = exp.Replace(str, "CInt($1)")
```

But this will match the entire string and replace it.

I was thinking of doing a recursive function to find the outer most match, and then work inwards, but that still presents a problem with things like

```
CType(replaceChars(I), Int32)), Chr(CType(replacementChars(I), Int32)
```

Any tips would be appreciated.

Input

```
returnString.Replace(Chr(CType(replaceChars(I), Int32)), Chr(CType(replacementChars(I), Int32)))
```

Output:

```
 returnString.Replace(Chr(CInt(replaceChars(I))),Chr(CInt(replacementChars(I))))
```

Edit:

Been working on it a little more and have a recursive function that I'm still working out the kinks in.  Recursion + regex.  it kinda hurts.

```
 Private Function FindReplaceCInts(ByVal strAs As String) As String
    System.Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Testing : {0}", strAs))
    Dim exp As New Regex("CType\((.+), Int32\)")
    If exp.Match(strAs).Success Then

        For Each match As Match In exp.Matches(strAs)

            If exp.Match(match.Value.Substring(2)).Success Then
                Dim replaceT As String = match.Value.Substring(2)
                Dim Witht As String = FindReplaceCInts(match.Value.Substring(2))
                System.Console.WriteLine(strAs.IndexOf(replaceT))
                strAs.Replace(replaceT, Witht)
            End If

        Next

        strAs = exp.Replace(strAs, "CInt($1)")
    End If

    Return strAs
End Function
```

Cheers,

Comment: is doing it with code a must? Or u can even use the IDE find and replace with regex?

Comment: I've played with it a bit, but it is still necessary to find a good regex to match the Ctypes.  I've thought about a recursive function to do this, but haven't quite wrapped my head around it.  I'm not certain how the replace works in the vs 2010 IDE to be able to do match capturing in the replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you guys think of this?

I think it does it quite nicely for a variety of cases that I have tested so far...

```
Private Function FindReplaceCInts(ByVal strAs As String) As String
    Dim exp As New Regex("CType\((.+), Int32\)")
    If exp.Match(strAs).Success Then

        For Each match As Match In exp.Matches(strAs)

            If exp.Match(match.Value.Substring(2)).Success Then
                Dim replaceT As String = match.Value.Substring(2)
                Dim Witht As String = FindReplaceCInts(match.Value.Substring(2))
                strAs = strAs.Replace(replaceT, Witht)
            End If

        Next

        strAs = exp.Replace(strAs, "CInt($1)")
    End If

    Return strAs
End Function
```

Comment: It is a solution. I also thought about combine regex with recursion or some stringBuilder logic. But I was looking for pure regex solution. And I'm not sure if it is possible

Comment: I appreciate your help.  What sort of StringBuilder logic might be applicable?

Comment: I think about matching not CType and INt32, but content between CType and Int32: Ctype(match this, Int32) and then with string builder add CInt before each match.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  There is not going to be anything particularly unique about the expression in the Ctype, and it can even be arbitrarily complex.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this `(?!CType\(.+, )Int32` regex instead of yours
You need to use negative look ahead to accomplish your task.

Check regex at [this site](http://regexr.com?2speu)

Comment: Very cool site.  However, It does not seem to be matching/ replacing correctly in my test script  With an input of CType(expression, Int32)  and a replace of CInt($1) i get the output CType(expression, CInt($1))

Comment: Not understand clearly what is the problem. Yes, you will get the output you write. It is not a problem of regex. It is a problem of your code. Could you edit post with example as string input, string output you want to see, that I clearly understand your needs. As for me, 95% of your task has been done

Comment: I think you did not understand what I was looking for.  The regex that you gave me found the Int32s, however, It also found them within the signature of methods.  I added an input and output for you.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I will think about other solution

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this in VS 2008 (no copy of VS 2010 to try it out), using the Find & Replace dialog:

Regular Expression:  `CType\({.+}, Int32\)`

Replace With: `CInt(\1)`

It won't fix the nested situations in one pass, but you should be able to continue searching with that pattern and replacing until no other matches are found.

BTW: That dialog also provides a link to this help page explaining characters used the VS flavor of regex http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa293063(VS.71).aspx